# How to get unique AWS subnet IDs per AZ using data source in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The VPC needs to attach with the transit gateway, the code:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "vpc_live" {
  subnet_ids         = toset(data.aws_subnets.vpc_live.ids)
  transit_gateway_id = var.tgw_id
  vpc_id             = var.vpc_id
}
```

data source:

```
data "aws_subnets" "vpc_live" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: updating EC2 Transit Gateway VPC Attachment (tgw-attach-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): InvalidParameterValue: AddSubnets values count greater than region availability zones
│   status code: 400, request id: dnc3c5d-8927-029c-9fd5-311c3c5b5046
│
│   with aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.vpc_live,
│   on main.tf line 7, in resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "vpc_live":
│    7: resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "vpc_live" {
```

I understand it requires only one subnet-id per availability zone (AZ). I have been searching everywhere in their GitHub issues, StackOverflow, but I am wondering if nobody has faced this primary issue.

So my question is, how can I filter my data source in such a way that it returns only 1 subnet ID per AZ?

Comment: I doubt the aws provider would offer something like that out of the box. How should it determine which subnets to return? Do you really not care about which subnets to add? Why not? Why do you have multiple subnets but do not differentiate them in any way and care not about which one the TGW gets attached to?

Comment: They are legacy VPCs and they are quite high in numbers (100+). So it's not easy to change the design all of a sudden in 1 day, just because we would like to attach them to TGW to achieve our project goal :D. But, never mind, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you have instance in the subnets and then just randomly attach a TGW to some what do you expect to happen? Some instances can use the TGW but the others can't. Why? *You* need to determine which subnets to use.

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry but that's not how TGW works. Please check out their documentation. 
> You can select only one subnet per Availability Zone. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-vpc-attachments.html). 

So it really does not matter which subnet you are picking up from that AZ. Irrespectively, it will work for all the ec2 instances belonging to that AZ (even though their subnet is not attached to TGW).

Comment: Good to know. And then you would need a lot of manually created route table entries, interesting... In that case I would recommend to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones to know the AZs in your current region. Then do https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet with a count / foreach, once for each AZ, therefore getting one Subnet per AZ. That only works if you have a subnet in each AZ.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a subnet resource for each subnet you get from the the subnets, then iterate through all the subnet and collect them into a map based on their az, then get the values of the map, therefore retrieving exactly one subnet for each used AZ.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for the explanation. I think what @alok has commented below is exactly what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's quite easy:

First, get all the availability zones attached to each subnet:

```
data "aws_subnet" "vpc_live" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.vpc_live.ids)
  id       = each.key
}
```

Second, do the reverse. Get all the subnets belongs to those AZs:

```
{ for s in data.aws_subnet.vpc_live : s.availability_zone => s.id... }
```

Finally, pick the first subnet on the index from all AZs:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "vpc_live" {
  subnet_ids         = [for subnet_ids in { for s in data.aws_subnet.ids : s.availability_zone => s.id... } : subnet_ids[0]]
  transit_gateway_id = var.tgw_id
  vpc_id             = var.vpc_id
}
```

I ran the code on my system, and check the output:

```
subnets_ids = [
    + "subnet-xxxx123",
    + "subnet-xxxx456",
    + "subnet-xxxx789",
  ]
```